# process output is much slower than with cmd

Tags: c#, winforms, process, plink

I need to run PLink as a process as part of WinForm application 
this is my code

```
     public void RunProcess(string FileName, string Arguments, bool EventWhenExit , bool IsWaitBeforeStart = true )
     {
        process = new Process();
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceivedEvent);//**
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = FileName; // Gets or sets the application or document to start.
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;//Gets or sets the set of command-line arguments to use when starting the application      
        if (IsWaitBeforeStart) Thread.Sleep(5000);
        if (EventWhenExit)
        {
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            process.Exited += new EventHandler(myprocess_Exited);

        }           
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        PID = process.Id;
        ProcessTimeOut.Enabled = true;
        ProcessInputStream = process.StandardInput;
        ProcessTimeOut.Enabled = false;            
    }


private void OnDataReceivedEvent(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
 //prints to screen using control.invoke
 //add data to a string list
}
```

My setup consist of a telnet server that I need to run few command on it and parse the result 
if I run the application from cmd it prints the result under one sec (it is about 50 rows)
but if I run it using my code it takes up to almost 7 sec !

From my understanding process.start() and running via cmd should be the same 
so the problem should be somewhere in my code or logic

what can be the problem ?

Comment: IsWaitBeforeStart is true maybe?

Comment: I wish it was the problem :(

Comment: The problem is with control.invoke. When you invoke something your work thread waits until the UI thread finishes doing whats it doing and then goes back into your work thread. You can test it quickly with just printing the data out at the end or not accesing any UI elements.

Comment: For solving this you need to create a second thread. Your work thread should save the data you want to show to a List your second thread should be running in a loop and look if there is anything in that List if there is invoke the control from this second thread to print out the data into a textbox or whatever and delete the entry from the list you used. If you need help making this i can help you in around 1 hour when i get home if someone else doesnt

Comment: wow @Vajura If you'll do it I'll be forever in your debt !! 
In the mean while I'll try implement it by myself:)

Comment: @Vajura I've just checked my code , without printing to textbox it is about 3 sec long , with printing it get close to 25 sec ! 
so you are spot-on on the problem

Comment: @LordTitiKaka sry was busy yesterday do you still need it? Its pretty easy to do so its no trouble

Comment: @Vajura I want to give it a try by myself (there is no other way to learn :) )

Comment: @LordTitiKaka alright tell me if you need help

Comment: @Vajura I've added an answer ,If it not too much to ask , please tell me what do think about the implementation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so with help from **Vajura** comment I've made a simple(vary) buffer to implement simple consumer/producer pattern

inside RunProcess :

```
     public void RunProcess(string FileName, string Arguments, bool EventWhenExit , bool IsWaitBeforeStart = true )
 {
   //... same code as before 
   PollingService();    
 }
```

second changing the event `DataReceivedEventHandler`

to store data to buffer (and stop invoking the print to UI)
the code is something like `ProcessLog.Add(e.Data);`

now for the second Thread to run over the buffer :

```
        private void PollingService()
    {
        var T = new Thread (()=>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (ProcessLogIndex < ProcessLog.Count)
                {
                    lock (this)
                    {
                        var tempList = ProcessLog.GetRange(ProcessLogIndex, ProcessLog.Count - ProcessLogIndex);
                        ProcessLogIndex = ProcessLog.Count;
                        foreach (var cell in tempList)
                        {

                            string ToSend = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell) ? (cell.Contains('$') ? cell.Substring(cell.LastIndexOf('$')) : cell) : "";
                            onDataOutputFromProcess(this, ToSend, Proc.ToString());
                        }

                    }

                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });
        T.IsBackground = true;
        T.Start();
    }
```

Comment: I am doing it a bit difrently, i start the second thread before the work thread and only do it once, but you can also do it this way. I have some questions tho, everytime you want to send data to your UI you start a new thread right? Or is the PollingService only executed once? Also how do you stop the thread when it finishes its batch of work?

Comment: the pollingService is running once per process , once I want to send data to UI I fire Event which handles all data collect form various process handle some logic (to which screen to send mainly )  and fire another event to the UI layer , I dont sure if it is the best to perform this but it made sense for me when I wrote it .
once process ceased I remove this(pollingService) thread as well